# Python Regex - Match Number Hyphen Number

Tags: python, regex

Trying find the right Regex expression to match a (2 or 3) digit number followed by a hyphen followed by a (9, 10, or 11) digit number.

In all, there are six (6) potential permutations of the string.

```
##-######### (2-9)
##-########## (2-10)
##-########### (2-11)
###-######### (3-9)
###-########## (3-10)
###-########### (3-11)
```

Comment: What about negative numeric values?

Comment: @MateuszKleinert Good call!  Negative numeric values would not occur in this situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regex will look like this: `\d{2,3}-\d{9,11}`

- `\d` represents`0-9`
- `{x,y}` is how many times the preceding character repeats

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this expression:

```
r'\d{2,3}-\d{9,11}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct regex answer is `r"([2-3])(-)(9|(1(?:0|1)))"`

```
import re
string = "23-11315310"
match = re.findall( r"([2-3]-)(9|(1(?:0|1)))", string )
matched = []
for i in range( len(match) ):
    matched.append( match[i][0] + match[i][1] )
print( matched )
```

String `"23-11315310"`
Output:
`['3-11']`
String `"23-92-113-105-702-052-153-10"`
Output:
`['3-9', '2-11', '3-10', '3-10']`